# Programmatically Created DataTable Column MaxLength Error

Tags: c#, asp.net

I've got a situation where I need to modify an existing `DataTable`. @Shai Cohen has provided the code but because live data differs I get an exception MaxLimit violation on the column I'm modifying.

I've tried to change the with in the code but it keeps on throwing the error. Here is the code (See my comments within):

```
public DataTable PrepareDataTable(DataTable dtResults)
{
   string[] subCategories = new string[3] {"Critical Down Time", "Critical Outage", "Total Repair Time"};

    DataTable dtOutput = dtResults.Clone();
    DataRow drOutput = null;
    DataRow[] drResults = null;
    var categories = dtResults.AsEnumerable().Select(r => r["Category"]).Distinct().ToList();

    foreach (string category in categories)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < subCategories.Length    ; i++)
        {
            drOutput = dtOutput.NewRow();
            drOutput["Category"] = category;
            drOutput["SubCategory"] = subCategories[i];
            drResults = dtResults.Select(String.Format("Category = '{0}' AND SubCategory = '{1}'", category, subCategories[i]));
            if(drResults.Length > 0)
            {
                foreach(DataColumn column in dtResults.Columns)
                {

                     drOutput[column.ColumnName] = drResults[0][column.ColumnName];
    **I've tried**   drOutput[column.MaxLength] = Unit.Pixel(500);
    **or just a number but no use**       

                }
            }
     **Error >>>** dtOutput.Rows.Add(drOutput);
        }

        drOutput = dtOutput.NewRow();
        dtOutput.Rows.Add(drOutput);
    }
    return dtOutput;
}
```

Comment: Why are pixels involved here?

Comment: What is the exception?

Comment: Why the downvote???? @AlexFilipovici i've stated in at the top MaxLimit violation... Pixels, because I dont know what else - that is why post here as I'm not an expert.

Answer (score 1):

Your line:

```
drOutput[column.MaxLength]
```

Is trying to grab a particular column from the row... in this case, not the first column or second column, but the column.MaxLength column.

Try:

```
drOutput.Table.Columns[column.ColumnName].MaxLength = some_length;
```

Comment: @Risho, any feedback on Grant's answer?

Comment: I can't reproduce the error, but I've also tried @Grant's version but it didn't work. I'll keep trying though as the issue couldn't just vanish.